# Apache kafka connect - custom websocket connector

Tags: java, apache-kafka, websocket, apache-kafka-connect

The goal is :develop a custom Kafka connector that read ,messages from the websocket in a loop method. I try to give you an example on what I've realized:

I create an interface IWebsocketClientEndpoint

```
    public interface IWebsocketClientEndpoint {
    IWebsocketClientEndpoint Connect() ;
    void Disconnect() throws IOException;
    IWebsocketClientEndpoint addMessageHandler(IMessageHandler msgHandler);
    void SendMessage(String message) throws Exception;
    void SendMessage(ByteBuffer message) throws Exception;
    void SendMessage(Object message) throws Exception;
    boolean isOpen();
    void Dispose()throws IOException;
}
```

and a class that implement above interface:

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class WebsocketClientEndpoint implements IWebsocketClientEndpoint {

    private WebSocketContainer _container;
    private Session _userSession = null;
    private IMessageHandler _messageHandler;
    private URI _endpointURI;

    private WebsocketClientEndpoint(URI endpointURI) {
        try {
            _endpointURI = endpointURI;
            _container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    private WebsocketClientEndpoint(URI endpointURI, int bufferSize) {
        try {
            _endpointURI = endpointURI;
            _container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
            _container.setDefaultMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(bufferSize);
            _container.setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(bufferSize);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

  
    public static IWebsocketClientEndpoint Create(URI endpointURI){
        return new WebsocketClientEndpoint(endpointURI);
    }

    public static IWebsocketClientEndpoint Create(URI endpointURI,int bufferSize){
        return new WebsocketClientEndpoint(endpointURI,bufferSize);
    }

    public IWebsocketClientEndpoint Connect()  {
        try {
                      _container.connectToServer(this, _endpointURI);
            return this;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session userSession) {
        this._userSession = userSession;

       if (this._messageHandler != null) {
            this._messageHandler.handleOpen("Web socket "+ _endpointURI +" opened");}
    }


    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session userSession, CloseReason reason) {

        this._userSession = null;

        if (this._messageHandler != null) {
            this._messageHandler.handleClose("Web socket "+ _endpointURI +" closed. Reason: " + reason.getReasonPhrase());}
    }

    public void Disconnect() throws IOException {
        CloseReason reason  = new CloseReason(CloseReason.CloseCodes.NORMAL_CLOSURE,"Web socket closed by user");

        this._userSession.close(reason);
        this._userSession = null;
        //close notification to caller
        if (this._messageHandler != null) {
            this._messageHandler.handleClose("Web socket "+ _endpointURI +" closed. Reason: " + reason.getReasonPhrase());}
    }

    @Override
    public IWebsocketClientEndpoint addMessageHandler(IMessageHandler msgHandler) {
        this._messageHandler = msgHandler;
        return  this;
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        if (this._messageHandler != null) {
            this._messageHandler.handleMessage(message);
        }
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(ByteBuffer bytes) {

        if (this._messageHandler != null) {
            this._messageHandler.handleMessage(bytes);
        }
    }

    public void SendMessage(String message) throws Exception {
        try{
           this._userSession.getAsyncRemote().sendText(message);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public void SendMessage(ByteBuffer message) throws Exception {
        try{
            this._userSession.getAsyncRemote().sendBinary(message);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            throw ex;
        }
    }


    public void SendMessage(Object message) throws Exception {
            this._userSession.getAsyncRemote().sendObject(message);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOpen() {
        if (this._userSession != null){
            return  this._userSession.isOpen();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The class WebsocketClientEndpoint is dedicated to the creation of websocket and manage of connection, disconnection, send and receive message.

The goal is: how can I adapt the my websocket structure in the kafka connect structure? I could queue the message received ("public void handleMessage(String s)) from the socket in a ConcurrentLinkedQueue, and then, in the kafka connect loop method, unqueue them. But is it the best solution?

Below, the implementation of my Kafka custom connector

```
My kafka Connector

public class MySourceTask extends SourceTask {
IWebsocketClientEndpoint _clientEndPoint;

    @Override
    public void start(Map<String, String> props) {

                _clientEndPoint = WebsocketClientEndpoint
                        .Create(new URI(socket))
                        .Connect();

            _clientEndPoint.addMessageHandler(new IMessageHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void handleMessage(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {

                }

                @Override
                public void handleClose(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void handleOpen(String s) {

                }
            });
     
    }

    @Override
    public List<SourceRecord> poll() throws InterruptedException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
            _clientEndPoint.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone

Comment: Methods should start with a lowercase letter, by the way. Java is not C#

Comment: Yes, I know. But unfortunately I'm a .Net dev, so my mindset is setted on C# 

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding the interface to the class

```
extends SourceTask implements IMessageHandler
```

Then

```
_clientEndPoint.addMessageHandler(this);
```

And when you implement `handleMessage`, add those strings to some queue. Inside the `poll` method, you would pop data off that queue to create SourceRecord objects to return.

Inside of `stop`, call `this.handleClose` and clean up other resources.